# Port forwarding with private IP

Tags: networking, portforwarding

I use a static IP connection, Configured to TPLINK router.
 I have a local server running which i can access from my network, but i want it to be accessed outside network. 
So I did port forwarding. and its Successfully running.

**Now the problem is :: The IP address of my WAN is also a private address like 10.10.X.X, so when am entering http://10.10.X.X, i can access my site, but not outside my network. Please guide me how to fix this?**

Answer (score 2):

If your WAN address is a private address, your ISP is using CGN. This is becoming more common since the RIRs have, or soon will, run out of public IP addresses to assign to ISPs. It sounds like your ISP has run out of public addresses and needs to use private addresses for its residential customers, reserving its remaining public addresses for its business customers which are willing to pay for public addresses.

Basically, your ISP is using NAT, too. You would need to have the ISP forward your port on its NAT router, but the odds of that are zero since it probably has a policy you agreed to to not host servers on your residential LAN (buried in the fine print of the ISP agreement). This situation will play out more and more over time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the "Virtual Server" settings. Port triggering is used for.

Once the modem router is configured, the operation is as follows: 1. A local host makes an outgoing connection to an external host using a destination port number defined in the Trigger Port field. 2. The modem router records this connection, opens the incoming port or ports associated with this entry in the Port Triggering table, and associates them with the local host. 3. When necessary, the external host will be able to connect to the local host using one of the ports defined in the Incoming Ports field.
It is not used for incoming connections which are triggered from outside!

Of course, to have it working you have to have an application listening on that port not only having the firewall on Windows allowing the port.

After you set up the "Virtual Server" a port scanner should show you the port is open (even without having a running application listening) - it will try to port forward it. I use ShieldsUp for testing.